# How to change state of nested formly form to readonly on click of a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, nested-forms, angular-formly

My problem is pretty straight forward.

**Things that I have.**

-- A form (formly) which I made using the data (JSON) received form the backend.

-- The form is going to be Multilevel Nested (currently its two level nested).

-- There is a repeater associated to every nested form element that will add another element to the form on click of a button.

-- There is going to be a button on the top of the page that will toggle the state of the form elements to readOnly.

**Problem that I am facing**

-- When I click the button, the state of the form elements change to readOnly, **except the ones that are nested**.

**What I want**

--When I click the button, every single element of my form should change its state to readOnly, nested or not.

Here is the controller...Followed by JS-Bin link.

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl(formlyVersion) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.onSubmit = onSubmit;
  vm.exampleTitle = 'Nested Repeating Section';
  vm.options = {
    formState: {
      readOnly: true
    }
  };

  init();

  vm.originalFields = angular.copy(vm.fields);


  function onSubmit() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(vm.model), null, 2);
  }


  function init() {
    vm.fields = [{
      key: 'name',
      type: 'input',

      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Name',
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 25
      }
    }, {
      key: 'description',
      type: 'textarea',

      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Description',
        rows: 5,
        maxlength: 100
      }
    }, {
      wrapper: 'panel',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Cars'
      },
      fieldGroup: [{
        type: 'repeatSection',
        key: 'cars',
        templateOptions: {
          btnText: '+',
          fields: [{

            wrapper: 'panel',
            templateOptions: {
              label: 'New car'
            },
            fieldGroup: [{
              key: 'carname',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: 'Name',
                required: true,
                maxlength: 25
              }
            }, {
              key: 'cardesc',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: 'Description',
                maxlength: 50
              }
            }]
          }]
        }
      }]
    }];
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/sunocaf/edit?html,js,output

Thanks in advance

P.S. - I took the example from the official angular formly website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a work around to my problem. I am still controlling the disable function via a button, the only difference is that I am using a separate controller for the repeated section of my form.

That way I can provide a flag using a data service to the repeated section's controller in order to make it disabled along with the whole form.

To achieve this I had to tweak the repeated section's wrapper a bit, but the end result was just what I wanted.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This will only make inputs readOnly, and will not affect radio buttons or checkboxes.  Buttons either for that matter.

To do what you want, set the ng-click event in the button to:

```
ng-click="readOnly()"
```

then in the controller:

```
   $scope.readOnly = function() {
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
   };
```

This will prevent any input from occurring.  If you need to hide/disable buttons you can set a readOnly flag to true and have an ng-show or an ng-disabled on the button set to !model.readOnly.

If you want to pretend you are using angular instead of jQuery, even though angular.element is an ALIAS for jQuery(straight out of the angular docs), then  you could do:

```
 $scope.readOnly = function() {
     angular.element(function() {
            angular.element('input').trigger('click')(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            };
       });
 };
```

Comment: Thanks MattE for the answer. Although I didn't use your way since I was able to make it work about a month ago. I am gonna post the solution that I used. Thanks again...Cheers!!